# error installing rmagick gem on OSX - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rmagick, extconf.rb

I have installed about 40 other gems but this one can't install due to this error:

Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /Users/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /Users/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@ruby1.9.2_Abroad101/bin:/Users/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/durrantm/.rvm/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/PostreSQL/9.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/durrantm/.rvm/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@ruby1.9.2_Abroad101/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@ruby1.9.2_Abroad101/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.

I tried this link  https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer
but it errored out at the end with:
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./builds/unix/freetype2.pc \
          /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Right now I am trying Veraticus' solution, then I will try Peters if necessary.

Comment: I'm also getting this "Unrecognized archive format" error when RVM tries to install rubygems on Mountain Lion. I'm going to see if installing gnu tar helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I found [here](http://logicbox.tumblr.com/post/17086714059/the-rmagic-gem-ubuntu) perfectly works on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

and then,

```
bundle install
```

as usual.

HTH

Comment: @Dave Newton: Offtopic - but - I admitted that this is for Ubuntu. - Just to make it clear - I didn't want to open a new question and answer myself. Ubuntu users have the same issue, and google will bring you here when you're looking for the solution. So why not?

Answer (score 3):

Installing rmagick is always a pain...

If you're having trouble, I'd step back and use Homebrew to reinstall Imagemagick. (This can usually be accomplished with `brew install imagemagick`.) Make sure to follow any follow-up instructions homebrew gives you, and then try installing the gem once again.

Comment: I tried it but I got this weird errors:  `$ brew install imagemagick
==> Installing imagemagick dependency: jpeg  
==> Downloading http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8d.tar.gz  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.ijg.org; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Error: Download failed: http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8d.tar.gz
$`

Comment: Sounds like you can't reach www.ijg.org for some reason. Can you ping that host, or go to that website? If not, you might want to investigate your router or DNS configuration.

Comment: it was a network issue that resolved, but then I got a different one - no such file - (see question) that I could not resolve.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by following these steps:

1. Downgrade image-magics from 7 to 6 by running brew install imagemagick@6.
2. then run PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure, you installed ImageMagick. If you have it, try to reinstall with [that script](https://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl)

Comment: I tried but I got an error - `Downloading ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/libpng/png/src/libpng-1.4.8.tar.gz

curl: (78) RETR response: 550
ls: libpng-1.4.8.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Failed download: ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/libpng/png/src/libpng-1.4.8.tar.gz, size: B, aborting.` Sorry to downvote because of that but the answer didn't work.  Happy to reverse though...